# How to query submenu with menu in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

This is my welcome controller code:

```
 public function index() {
    $data = array();
    $data['title'] = '। All User ।';
    $data['logo_image'] = $this->sv_model->select_logo_image();
    $data['all_footer'] = $this->sv_model->select_all_published_footer();
    $data['all_welcome'] = $this->sv_model->select_all_published_welcome();
    $data['all_notification'] = $this->sv_model->select_all_published_notification();
    $data['all_chairman_gallery_image'] = $this->sv_model->select_all_chairman_gallery_image();
    $data['all_gallery_image'] = $this->sv_model->select_all_gallery_image();
    $data['all_country'] = $this->sv_model->select_all_country();
    $data['all_district'] = $this->sv_model->select_all_district();
    $data['all_user'] = $this->sv_model->select_all_user();
    //echo '<pre>';
    //print_r($data);
    // exit();
    $this->load->view('welcome_message', $data);
}
```

I have 2 tables in my Database called **'tbl_country'** and **'tbl_district'**

> tbl_countrycontains 2 field(country_id,country_name) tbl_district
>   contains 3 field(district_id,country_id,district_name)

Now I want to view **'country name'** as **'main menu'** and **'district name** as **'sub_menu'**..
Now what should I call in view?
I have used foreach() loop to view main menu, but can't do it with submenu.

My model:

```
public function select_all_district() {
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('tbl_district');
    $query_result = $this->db->get();
    $result = $query_result->result();
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: The easiest analogy which most php developers follow ism use html in your view and put it inside foreach after you have desired design. Show us your view or anything you have tried, there are lot of tutorials on web

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You call the foreach for the country. In this foreach, you have to call again a foreach for the districts..

There are 2 possibilities. You have ordered them in an array by country_id index

```
$country_id = $country['country_id'];
foreach($all_district[$country_id] as $district)
{
     echo $district['district_name'];
}
```

Or the second way is to check every district if it match against the country_id (from the upper menu/country

```
foreach($all_district as $district)
    {
        if($district['country_id'] == $country['id])
        {
        echo $district['district_name'];
        }
    }
```

Maybe you can give us the structure of the array? Or the model? What do you already have in the view?

Comment: <?php
                            foreach ($all_district['country_id'] as $district) {
                                ?>
                                <li><a href="#"><?php echo $district->district_name; ?></a>

                                </li>
                                   
                            <?php } ?>
                        </ul>                                         I have put my code like this...but i have got an error which says--undefined index:country_id....